# How can a function return self-defined struct?

Tags: c

I am trying to scan the input file inside a function, instead of scaning the inputfile in the main function. but seems like it doesn't work this way.
I guess it's the problem of the inputfile pointer, I am not very familiar with using pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>

typedef struct 
{
    char firstname[32],lastname[32];
    int age;
}mandef;

mandef scaninput(int rows,FILE *inputfile)
{
    int i;
    mandef man[rows];
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i ++)
    {
        fscanf(inputfile,"%s",&man[i].firstname);
        fscanf(inputfile,"%s",&man[i].lastname);
        fscanf(inputfile,"%d",&man[i].age);
    }
    return man;
}

int main ()
{
    FILE *inputfile;
    inputfile = fopen("input.txt","r");
    if (inputfile == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error: Unable to open input.txt.");
        return(1);
    }
    int i,rows;
    char x;
    fscanf(inputfile,"%d",&rows);
    mandef man[rows];
    man = scaninput(rows,inputfile);
    return 0;
}
```

I want the code works the same way as this code

```
#include<stdio.h>
typedef struct 
{
    char firstname[32],lastname[32];
    int age;
}mandef;

int main ()
{
    FILE *inputfile;
    inputfile = fopen("input.txt","r");
    if (inputfile == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error: Unable to open input.txt.");
        return(1);
    }
    int i,rows;
    fscanf(inputfile,"%d",&rows);
    mandef man[rows];
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i ++)
    {
        fscanf(inputfile,"%s",&man[i].firstname);
        fscanf(inputfile,"%s",&man[i].lastname);
        fscanf(inputfile,"%d",&man[i].age);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

input.txt looks like

```
2
Mike Abc 18
David Abc 17
```

Comment: Unrelated to structs. You are returning an element of array one past the arrays end. Also not clear why you are populating the whole array while returning only one element.

Comment: "but seems like it doesn't work this way": Please explain what this means.  What were you expecting to happen, and what happened instead?

Comment: You can return *one* struct, but you are trying to return an out-of-bounds one. And the caller is doing likewise with `man[rows] = scaninput(rows,inputfile);` The only time you can use `man[rows]` is when *defining* the variable.

Comment: What do you want to return? (The code is incorrect anyway as it accesses an array out of bound)

Comment: Opps I forgot about man[rows], I edited the question to make it clear

Comment: after your edit, you are now trying to return a Variable Length Array of `mandef` from a function that is supposed to return a single `mandef`.  Further more, a block-scoped array should never be returned from a function because it will decay to a pointer to said array, which will go out of scope and be invalid upon returning.

Comment: Too many critical bugs in your code:
1. in function scaninput, your function should return a struct of type mandef and you are returning an array (pointer) of structs !!!??
2. The worst bug that a c programmer can do, is to return an address from a function stack frame to the caller ! Do you know what happens when the function scaninput return to main (or any other function), all its stack frame is rewind and marked as free. you are holding iligal dangling adress in man. 
Any way this code shall not pass compilation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You return the local variable, it's a bad idea because after the function terminated, this variable may be doesnt existe. So you should use pointer instead:

```
mandef * man = malloc(sizeof(mandef) * rows);
if(!mandef) {
   // handle the error
}
```

Do not use `&` for scanning the string, it should be:

```
        fscanf(inputfile,"%s",man[i].firstname);
        fscanf(inputfile,"%s",man[i].lastname);
        fscanf(inputfile,"%d",&man[i].age);
```

the test:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct 
{
    char firstname[32],lastname[32];
    int age;
}mandef;

mandef * scaninput(int rows,FILE *inputfile)
{
    int i;
    mandef * man = malloc(sizeof(mandef) * rows);
    if (!man) {
        return NULL;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i ++)
    {
        fscanf(inputfile,"%s",man[i].firstname);
        fscanf(inputfile,"%s",man[i].lastname);
        fscanf(inputfile,"%d",&man[i].age);
    }
    return man;
}

int main ()
{
    FILE *inputfile;
    inputfile = fopen("input.txt","r");
    if (inputfile == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error: Unable to open input.txt.");
        return(1);
    }
    int i,rows;
    char x;
    fscanf(inputfile,"%d",&rows);
    if(rows <= 0)
       return -1;
    mandef * man;
    man = scaninput(rows,inputfile);
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i ++)
    {
        printf("%s\n",man[i].firstname);
        printf("%s\n",man[i].lastname);
        printf("%d\n",man[i].age);
    }
    free(man);
    return 0;
}
```

the output:

```
Mike                                                                                                                                            
Abc                                                                                                                                             
18                                                                                                                                              
David                                                                                                                                           
Abc                                                                                                                                             
17
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you figure out pointers and dynamically allocating memory for your array using malloc if that is appropriate. I made some quick changes to your code below, it's far from perfect but it should give you the general idea.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct mandef
{
    char firstname[32];
    char lastname[32];
    int age;
} mandef;

mandef *scaninput(int rows,FILE *inputfile)
{
    int i;
    mandef *man = malloc(sizeof(mandef) * rows);
    bzero(man, (sizeof(mandef) * rows));

    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        fscanf(inputfile,"%31s",man[i].firstname);
        fscanf(inputfile,"%31s",man[i].lastname);
        fscanf(inputfile,"%d",&man[i].age);
    }
    return man;
}

int main ()
{
    FILE *inputfile = fopen("input.txt","r");

    if (inputfile == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error: Unable to open input.txt.");
        return(1);
    }

    int rows=0;

    fscanf(inputfile,"%d",&rows);
    mandef *man = scaninput(rows,inputfile);
    if (rows > 0) 
    {
        printf("man[0].firstname is %s\n", man[0].firstname);
    }
    return 0;
}
```